# Create NumPy array from list with operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sqlite

I have data in a Python list from an SQLite database in the following format:

```
# This is an example
data = [(1, '12345', 1, 0, None), (1, '34567', 1, 1, None)]
```

From this list of tuples I want to create a 2D NumPy array, converting each tuple to an array. I also want the values at index 1 in the tuples converted from string to numbers, and the values at last index converted to 0 if None, 1 otherwise.

What it should look like afterwards:

```
transformed_data = np.asarray([[1, 12345, 1, 0, 0], [1, 34567, 1, 1, 0]])
```

I am able to with simple for loops, however I'd like a more Pythonic solution with native NumPy methods or otherwise. I am working with a very large database, so complexity matters.

Comment: "While doing so, I also want to be able to specify transformations on the data." I don't think you can do this all in one step. Do the transformations as a separate step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) is quite good at this:

```py
import pandas as pd
                      # set up DataFrame
transformed_data = (pd.DataFrame(data)
                      # convert to numeric
                      .apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
                      # replace null with 0
                      # trying to cast as integer if possible
                      .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
                      # convert to numpy array
                      .to_numpy()
                   )
```

output:

```py
array([[    1, 12345,     1,     0,     0],
       [    1, 34567,     1,     1,     0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If your tuple is small and of a fixed size then you can use a list comprehension:

```
result = [(a, int(b), c, d, 0 if e is None else e) for a, b, c, d, e in data]
```

Or a little shorter:

```
result = [(d[0], int(d[1]), *d[2:4], d[4] if d[4] else 0) for d in data]
```

Comment: This would work, however my tuples have over 500 elements so it would make the code quite convoluted